# What might cause this FOUC for my pseudo-element SVG-icons?

Tags: css, svg, background-image

I have a problem with FOUC for pseudo-elements on this site:

[image]

The code for each menu choice:

```
<div class="module">
  <a href="https://example.com/concierge/questions-about-oslo" class="headermenu__link headermenu__about-city active">
    <p>Questions about&nbsp;Oslo</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

I give each .module its icon with a pseudo-element like this:

```
a.headermenu__link:before {
  display: block;
  width: 3.3em;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}
.headermenu__about-city:before {
    content: url(./images/menu-icons_about-the-city.svg);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem was that I inserted the SVG in my content-attribute like this: `content: url(./images/menu-icons_about-the-city.svg);`. Apparently it's better to use it as a background, which makes it render *way* faster.

My new code now looks like this:

```
a.headermenu__link:before {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  height: 4em;
    background-position: center;
}
.headermenu__about-city:before {
  content: '';
  background: url(./images/menu-icons_about-the-city.svg) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Renders pretty much the same for me on your site. Quicker, but still a pop.

Comment: Ah! Your concern was the text moving?

Comment: No, the issue was the pop/flash/flicker of the icons. The previous flicker took way longer, and even worse, the whole page jumped down when they popped up. Now it's just a minor flicker, as with most webpages.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked at your site. I believe it's nothing more than browser rendering, I was going to suggest putting the SVG straight into the CSS, but I'm not sure it would help.

I think you just need to hide the whole element until all external content is rendered using JavaScript. For example:

```
$(window).load(function({
  $('.module').fadeIn();
}));
```

And then hide `.module` in CSS.

Comment: Shouldn't they be cached anyway? They're pretty small, the biggest one (the one in the gif) is 973 bytes.

Comment: Thanks, Chuck, tried this, but no avail. Won't that just duplicate the FOUC-behaviour anyway – i.e. collapse parent element until everything is rendered?

Comment: Appreciate the effort. Turned out my problem was that I had inserted the SVG in the content-attribute instead of using it as a background.